# Is $C_c^\infty$ a linear subspace of $L^1$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, vector-spaces

I have a quick question regarding those two spaces in the title.

Let $U$ be an open and bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $C_c^\infty(U)$ the space of infinitely differentiable functions with compact support in $U$. Furthermore, let $L^1(U)$ be the space of integrable functions over $U$.

What I know so far:

$C_c^\infty$ is a dense subset of $L^1$ and $L^1$ is a vector space. So for $C_c^\infty$ to be a linear subspace of $L^1$, we would have to show that it is closed with respect to scalar multiplication and vector addition. Scalar multiplication is trivial, but my question would be that the addition of two functions of $C_c^\infty$ are again in $C_c^\infty$. Is that true and if yes, how can it be seen?

Comment: It is equally trivial as scalar multiplication (the support of the sum is contained in the union of the supports and the union of compact sets is compact).

Comment: Ok thank you, I was just unsure about that property for the compact support!

Comment: If you don't like the abstract nonsense then $C^\infty_c(\Bbb{R}^n)$ are the smooth functions vanishing outside some ball $|x|\le  r$ and $C^\infty_c(U)$ are those $C^\infty_c(\Bbb{R}^n)$ functions vanishing outside some closed subset $V$ of $\Bbb{R}^n$ contained in $U$.